# USB stick won't show up

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a usb stick that won't show up on the computer. It has always worked in the past, and nothing remarkable has changed on the stick or the PC since its last use.

It could be that it's not getting power. The light doesn't show up, and other USB sticks work fine in that port. This stick doesn't work in any port on any PC that I've tried.

Is there any way of getting the data off it? Tall order I know...

Comment: Is it just on this PC or does it work elsewhere?

Comment: nvm, no light then it's most likely broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a tool for file and partition recovery from damaged/deleted/corrupt partitions. If that doesn't detect it, then it's unlikely you'll be able to get anything off. (If your running under Linux make sure you run it with sudo)

If like you say it's not getting power, then I would guess that something has failed internally. If the data is important take it to a specialist.

Comment: Thanks for that. TestDisk didn't detect it (good tip BTW - will keep it in mind), so I guess it's a lost cause.