# Computer does not detect usb stick

Tags: usb, memory, usb-flash-drive

My USB stick is not recognized by any computers and it does not seem to be working (the red indicator light was not on when plugged in). Other sticks work on the computers.

There is no trace of the USB stick in concern in Device manager and Disk Management.

It is strange because the USB stick functioned properly today in the morning. It became like what I described above after I pull it out of the port and then plug back in in the afternoon (without being damaged in any way when it is out of the port). The USB stick is about 5 years old.

How to fix this problem? If no, are there any ways to recover the data on the stick?

(I have looked at the other answers, which did not help with my issue.)

Comment: That's what they do when they break, hopefully you have that data backed up somewhere else. USB sticks should not be used for backup purposes. Flash memory recovery is very expensive and is not a do it yourself project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB stick won't show up](https://superuser.com/questions/11782/usb-stick-wont-show-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recover the data by wiggling the USB stick around as suggested by [this site](https://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/accessories/recover-retrieve-data-photos-files-from-usb-flash-stick-key-11364025840144).